# A hot-shot business man

Tags: adjectives

"Well-dressed and travels a lot. Are you some kind of hot-shot business man or something?"

- I see "hot-shot", "hotshot" an "hot shot" used. Are all of them correct?
- Is "hot-shot" a natural adjective to put on a business man who is successful?
- Would I sound jealous if I described someone as a "hot-shot business man"?

Answer (score 2):

> I see "hot-shot", "hotshot" an "hot shot" used. Are all of them correct?

All of those seem to be used to some extent. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hot-shot) suggests both "hotshot" and "hot shot", [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hotshot) mentions all three forms.

> Is "hot-shot" a natural adjective to put on a business man who is successful?

It's natural, but it's a very casual, slang expression.

> Would I sound jealous if I described someone as a "hot-shot business man"?

Not *necessarily*, but it is often used derisively - calling someone a hotshot person can mean they're impressing you, but can also imply that they're overconfident and showing off, depending on the context. In your example sentence, it's likely used with some degree of snark.